# Vertex Cover Problem

Tags: graph-theory

How to show that in every graph, the minimum size of a vertex cover is equal to number of vertices minus the maximum size of an independent set.

According to [Vertex cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover) two problem are not equivalent, but there are should be kind of connection between them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subset $C \subseteq V$ is a vertex cover iff

$$\forall (u,v) \in E. u \in C \vee v \in C$$

A subset $I \subseteq V$ is an independent set iff

$$\forall (u,v) \in E. u \notin I \vee v \notin I$$

So as you can see a set is a vertex cover iff its complement is an independent set, and the converse also holds.

Therefore a minimal vertex cover $C$ corresponds to a maximal independent set $V-C$.